# cURL script working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send a SMS through script. I am using curl to run the API sending the SMS on the vendor server.
fopen and file_get_contents are blocked on my server. So, cURL is my only option.

The script :-

```
// Initialize options for REST interface
$adb_url="http://example.com";
$adb_option_defaults = array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 2
  ); 
// ArangoDB REST function.
// Connection are created demand and closed by PHP on exit.
function adb_rest($method,$uri,$query=NULL,$json=NULL,$options=NULL){
    global $adb_url,$adb_handle,$adb_option_defaults;

    // Connect 
    if(!isset($adb_handle)) $adb_handle = curl_init();

    // Compose query
    $options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $adb_url.$uri."?".$query,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method, // GET POST PUT PATCH DELETE HEAD OPTIONS 
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json,
    CURLOPT_PORT => 8080,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => Array('Content-type: text/plain')
    ); 
    curl_setopt_array($adb_handle,($options + $adb_option_defaults)); 

    // send request and wait for responce
    $responce =  curl_exec($adb_handle);

    print_r(curl_getinfo($adb_handle));

    return($responce);
}
// Create a collection
$responce = adb_rest("GET","/bulksms/bulksms","username=xxx&password=xxx&type=2&dlr=1&destination=xxx&source=xxx&message=xxxxxx",'');
```

Live server cURL response :

```
Array ( 
   [url] => http://example.com/bulksms/bulksms?
username=xxx&password=xxx&type=2&dlr=1&destination=xxx&source=xxx&message=xxxxxx 
   [content_type] => 
   [http_code] => 0 
   [header_size] => 0 
   [request_size] => 0 
   [filetime] => -1 
   [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
   [redirect_count] => 0 
   [total_time] => 1.999604 
   [namelookup_time] => 1.315312 
   [connect_time] => 0 
   [pretransfer_time] => 0 
   [size_upload] => 0 
   [size_download] => 0 
   [speed_download] => 0 
   [speed_upload] => 0 
   [download_content_length] => -1
   [upload_content_length] => -1
   [starttransfer_time] => 0 
   [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [redirect_url] => )
```

Localhost cURL response :

```
Array (
   [url] => http://example.com/bulksms/bulksms?
username=xxx&password=xxx&type=2&dlr=1&destination=xxx&source=xxx&message=xxxxxx 
   [content_type] => text/plain
   [http_code] => 200
   [header_size] => 129
   [request_size] => 646
   [filetime] => -1
   [ssl_verify_result] => 0
   [redirect_count] => 0
   [total_time] => 0.14 
   [namelookup_time] => 0
   [connect_time] => 0.047
   [pretransfer_time] => 0.047
   [size_upload] => 0
   [size_download] => 54
   [speed_download] => 385
   [speed_upload] => 0 
   [download_content_length] => 54
   [upload_content_length] => 0
   [starttransfer_time] => 0.14
   [redirect_time] => 0
   [certinfo] => Array ( )
   [primary_ip] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
   [primary_port] => 8080
   [local_ip] => xxx.xxx.x.xxx
   [local_port] => 56359
   [redirect_url] => )
```

Through localhost I am getting an sms whereas through server I am not.

UPDATE -
Localhost php version :

```
PHP Version 5.4.3
```

Server php version :

```
PHP Version 5.3.27
```

Comment: if its not working on localhost and not on the live server, what does the "but" in the title mean? to me, it reads as "curl script not working at all"...

Comment: Sorry about that @Michael , just fixed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to say, but I would recommend adding `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` in addition to `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` to your curl options. I am setting `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` to `5` in this example. And set `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` to `TRUE`. Also, adding `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` as well just in case the remote server needs something as a user agent:

```
// Compose query
$options = array(
CURLOPT_URL => $adb_url.$uri."?".$query,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method, // GET POST PUT PATCH DELETE HEAD OPTIONS 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json,
CURLOPT_PORT => 8080,
CURLOPT_HTTPGET => TRUE,
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => Array('Content-type: text/plain')
); 
curl_setopt_array($adb_handle,($options + $adb_option_defaults));
```

Also, unclear if the PHP version on your local setup is the same as the server.