# curl and ie strange behavior when opening a web site

Tags: php, http, curl

I need to download a web page using curl or php-curl. However, when I use curl on my personal computer it works well. When I use curl on a remote server, it returns an empty web page. Also, when I open this page in IE in my own PC it shows the right content, but when I open it on a remote windows server, it just returns empty or something different to what I expect to see. Can someone tell me what could be the reason behind this?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075213/curl-request-not-working-on-live-server ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877703/curl-script-working-on-localhost-but-not-on-live-server

Comment: Do you  have code? Or shall we guess?